# Java hbm.xml multiple index of one column

Tags: java, hibernate, hbmxml

For example,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd" >
<hibernate-mapping package="com.sql.index">
    <class name="User">
        <id name="id" type="long">
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <property name="firstName" type="string" index="IDX_FIRST_NAME" />
        <property name="lastName" type="string" />
        <property name="address" type="string" />
        <property name="field_1" type="long" />
        <property name="field_2" type="long" />
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

If I want the `field_1` and `field_2` has 2 indexes description. Can I do the following thing? Or How to achieve it ?

```
        <property name="field_1" type="long" index="idx_1,idx_2"/>
        <property name="field_2" type="long" index="idx_1,idx_3"/>
```

The `field_1` and `field_2` will has 2 index for their self.

---

I refer the [hibernate 3.6, 5.1.4.2 Property mapping with hbm.xml](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-property), it seems like the `index` field can be assigned by `only one column`.

---

#### PS,

The project is some kind old, and is maintained by many people, so I cannot use annotation syntax to add `index`.

Comment: Your first approach with commas is correct

Comment: After trying, it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the [post](http://alvinalexander.com/java/jwarehouse/hibernate/hibernate-core/src/matrix/java/org/hibernate/test/sql/check/oracle-mappings.hbm.xml.shtml) and give it a try.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd" >
<hibernate-mapping package="com.sql.index">
    <class name="User">
        <id name="id" type="long">
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <property name="firstName" type="string" index="IDX_FIRST_NAME" />
        <property name="lastName" type="string" />
        <property name="address" type="string" />
        <property name="field_1" type="long" index="idx_2"/>
        <property name="field_2" type="long" index="idx_3"/>
    </class>
    <database-object>
        <create>
            CREATE INDEX idx_1 ON User (field_1, field_2)
        </create>
        <drop></drop>
    </database-object>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

---

This problem can be solved by `<database-object>`, by writing native sql syntax to create index.

---

#### UPDATE, 2018/11

For unique constraint with multiple properties, [someone has answered it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2741386/419348).

> Use `properties` tag

```
<properties name="uk1" unique="true">
        <property name="username" .../>
        <many-to-one name="client" .../>
</properties>

<properties name="uk2" unique="true">
        <property name="email" .../>
        <many-to-one name="client" update="false" insert="false" .../>
</properties>
```