# defining Unique Key in hibernate and how?

Tags: sql, hibernate, liquibase, unique-constraint, unique-key

```
<many-to-one name="attachment" class="AttachmentEntity" lazy="false"
             fetch="select" cascade="delete">
    <column name="SPA_ATTACHMENT_ID" not-null="true" unique-key="IDX_AMT_COND_01"/>
</many-to-one>
```

What is the Unique Key doing and how will it work as a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [JBoss documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/manual/en-US/html/ch21.html#toolsetguide-s1-2),

> A unique-key attribute can be used to group columns in a single,
>   unique key constraint. The attribute overrides the name of any
>   generated unique key constraint.

Typical use case for **unique-key** would be, when you want the values of multiple columns as a whole to be unique.

For example:

```
class Department {...}

class Employee {
  Integer employeeId;
  Department department;
}
```

So, *to ensure that 2 Employee objects with **same employeeId and department** are not persisted*, we can use the **unique-key** attribute with same value **EmpIdDept** on the 2 columns EMP_ID and DEPT_ID to *enforce the uniqueness constraint on them as a whole*:

```
<property name="employeeId" column="EMP_ID" unique-key="EmpIdDept"/>
<many-to-one name="department" column="DEPT_ID" class="Department" unique-key="EmpIdDept"/>
```

The string specified as the attribute value, i.e. **IDX_AMT_COND_01** in your case, is just the name of the multi column unique constraint.

Also check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741088/how-to-do-multiple-column-uniqueconstraint-in-hbm) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126769/uniqueconstraint-annotation-in-java) (to achieve the same using @UniqueConstraint)

> NOTE: to use single column unique constraint, you need to use
>   unique="true"